# How to deal with mutiple forms in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Short description of the page: user searches for an account (first form is to search for an account), account information gets displayed below and you can make changes to that account (second form).

I currently have this feature in only one form, but I am running into problems when I try to validate (since pressing any of the two buttons will try to validate all fields although that is not right, since if you are searching you don't need to fill out the other fields to edit).  Also, when I press enter in any of the text boxes the search button is clicked, how can I associate a text box to a particular button.

Comment: I need the button to cause validation, but only for certain text boxes, not all.

Comment: I should have mentioned. ASP.NET 1.1, meaning, no validation groups!

Comment: CausesValidation is a page thing, so if set to true, the page will check the IsValid status of all validators it contains. In my example below it shows how to get this to happen exactly the way you want, but there is loads of built in automatic niceness. Dan Answer may be more in line with what you ware after. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the CausesValidation attribute on your search button.

or you could use a custom validator like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TestBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Not" ID="CustomValidator1" Enabled="true"    
   ControlToValidate="TestBox"
   runat="server"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="myButton" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="TestClick" runat="server" />
```

Then have your button have an onclick command like this

```
public void TestClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.TestBox.Text == "me") this.CustomValidator1.IsValid = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Obviously set this false, and it should sort your problem.

Answer (score 4):

To only validate certain form fields you can add a common [ValidationGroup](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html) to all validators you require validating within that group and also the button that submits them. Alternatively, set the `CausesValidation` property of any button(s) you *don't* want to trigger validation when pressed.

You can also specify the [default button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) within `asp:panel`. This controls what button is fired when you hit enter within the panel. So, wrap a panel around your form and specify the button in the panel like so:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelForm" runat="Server" DefaultButton="ButtonSubmit">

    <!-- Form fields go here... -->

    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="Server" Text="Submit" />

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Forgot all about default button +1 :)

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't use this since the version of ASP.NET I am using (1.1) does not support it.